# SQL query with priority on OR condition

Tags: mysql, sql, xor

I have a sample table like this

```
+----+-------+--------+---------+
| Id | Type  | Format | Default |
+----+-------+--------+---------+
|  1 | IMAGE | PNG    | true    |
|  2 | IMAGE | PNG    | false   |
|  3 | IMAGE | JPG    | false   |
|  4 | IMAGE | JPG    | true    |
|  5 | VIDEO | MP4    | false   |
+----+-------+--------+---------+
```

And I need to implement a query like this

```
SELECT * FROM media WHERE type = 'IMAGE' and format = 'PNG'
```

If the query gives 0 results, the `format` filter need to be replaced with

```
SELECT * FROM media WHERE type = 'IMAGE' and default = TRUE
```

So, there is a fixed filter which is always there (on both attempts), for this example is made using `type = 'IMAGE'` and 2 filters that need to combined basing on the results size of the first condition

I'm trying to understand if there is a way to do a single query which can join both conditions, some sort of priority on the first condition `format` which will exclude the results from the second condition `default`

Something like this

```
SELECT * FROM media WHERE type = 'IMAGE' AND (format = 'PNG' OR default = TRUE)
```

is not suitable because no matter if the first condition give at least 1 result, the `OR` condition will always give the `default=TRUE` records.

I thought about the `XOR` operator, but it will exclude all the PNG results which are NOT default. Instead for the `format` filter the value of `default` is to be ignored

Is there a way to reproduce this behaviour using only 1 query?

The expected result

Example 1) It exists at least a PNG, so those are gathered (default or non default does not matter, the `format` filter have priority on that)

```
conditions = [format = 'PNG' | default = true]
|  1 | IMAGE | PNG    | true    |
|  2 | IMAGE | PNG    | false   |
```

Example 2) It exists at least a JPG, so those are gathered

```
conditions = [format = 'JPG' | default = true]
|  3 | IMAGE | JPG    | false   |
|  4 | IMAGE | JPG    | true    |
```

Example 3) No GIF exists, so all the default are gathered

```
conditions = [format = 'GIF' | default = true]
|  1 | IMAGE | PNG    | true    |
|  4 | IMAGE | JPG    | true    |
```

Comment: I added the expected result, please tell me if can be useful in that format

Comment: Check my answer below for the query suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a NOT EXIST clause together with the default=true predicate.

```
SELECT * FROM media
WHERE (format = 'PNG' AND type = 'IMAGE')
OR (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM media WHERE format = 'PNG' AND type = 'IMAGE')
AND default = 'true')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with two queries using `UNION` :

```
SELECT * FROM media WHERE type = 'IMAGE' and format = 'PNG'

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM media 
WHERE type = 'IMAGE' and default = TRUE  
  AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM media WHERE type = 'IMAGE' and format = 'PNG')
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering your **Priority based** query I think following query might actually work.

I have reproduced the same result as you have described above using following query.

```
SELECT * FROM media WHERE `type` = 'IMAGE' 
AND CASE WHEN (SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END FROM `media` WHERE `type` = 'IMAGE' AND `format` = 'PNG') = 1 
THEN `format` = 'PNG' ELSE `default` = 'true' END
```

The above query will look for total count of the ROWS by checking conditions include `type = 'IMAGE' AND format = 'PNG'` If found it will apply only `format = 'PNG'` condition otherwise it will look for data for based on condition `default = true`